# Understanding the proof of triangle inequality from point to set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This is proof given for the problem: if x,y are elements of X and A  is a set in X, prove d(x,A)<=d(x,y)+d(y,A)

[image]

The only part I don't get is the final step where you take the inf of the right-hand side. The triangle inequality holds for all z in A, but since the inf may not belong to the set, there is a sense that the inequality may not hold.

Also a more general question: Is it true that you can take the inf or sup of either just the left and right-hand side of the inequality and the inequality still holds?

Comment: The definition of the infimum of a bounded from below, non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the following: it is the maximum of all its lower bounds. Hence, if $d(x,A) - d(x,y) \leqslant d(x,z)$ forall $z$ in $A$, $d(x,A)-d(x,y)$ is a lower bound of $\{d(x,z)|z\in A\}$: the maximum of such lower bounds is thus greater.

Comment: The point is that for each $z_0 \in A$, we have $d \left( y, z_0 \right) \geq d \left( x, A \right) - d \left( x, y \right)$. Since the right hand side is only a constant, we conclude that the infimum over all possible $z_0 \in A$ is also greater than or equal to the right hand side of the inequality. This is precisely what we wanted.

Comment: oh ok i got it. I assumed taking an inf is like an algebraic operation where if you perform it on one side , you have to perform it on the other side as well, but basically, the set has a lower bound and by definition of R , it must have an infimum.

Comment: @William Not exactly: it is not an algebraic operation where you take it on both side. It is just looking back at its definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it as a consequence of a limit property of real numbers:

If $d_k \stackrel{k\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}d$ and $d_k \geq C$ for all $k$, then $d\geq C$.

Now, since $d(y,A) = \inf_{z\in A}d(y,z)$ you find a sequence of $z_k \in A$ such that
$d_k := d(y,z_k) \stackrel{k\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}d(y,A)$ and by definition of $d(y,A)$ you have $d_k \geq d(y,A)$. The claim follows from the above fact about limits.